# Postgresql: Create an insert query that inserts multiple records in a range

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm starting from a CSV file with a lot of zipcode in the form:

```
FROM;TO;CITY
1000;1200;TESTCITY
```

and I want to insert it in a postgres table with the columns:

- ZIPCODE : varchar
- CITYNAME : varchar

So, for each row in the CSV, I must create "TO - FROM" records in the table.

Is there a way to do this with a simple query, like

```
insert into zipcodes (zipcode, cityname) 
select RANGE(1000;1200), cityname;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use `generate_series`

```
insert into zipcodes (zipcode, cityname) 
SELECT  num,'TESTCITY' as cityname
FROM    generate_series(1000,1200) num
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d7f393/1)